# Using the correct word: IN or OUT OF

Tags: prepositions

According to Longman Contemporary Dictionary, ***out of***  is used to show *how large a part of a group you are talking about*, e.g.

> Nine out of ten students pass the test first time.

However, I read the following sentence in an English book:

> One ***in*** five fathers will be househusbands, while the mothers go out to work.

Can the word ***in*** be replaced with ***out of*** here? And would there be a difference in meaning?

Comment: *in* only works with "one". "one in five fathers" but "two/three/four/five out of five fathers". "one in ten students" but "two/three (etc.) out of ten students". *out of* can also be used with one, though.

Answer (score 1):

There is a more exact use of "out of", when the total figure is known, e.g. out of 392 students, 46 were left-handed, however "in" and "out of" are often used interchangeably to talk about a fraction or percentage of a population or total.